# Evaluate the volume of the solid determined by $x,y,z\in[0,1],z\geq xy$

Tags: solution-verification, volume

Evaluate the volume of the solid determined by $x,y,z\in[0,1],z\geq xy$

My calculations:

$$V=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_{xy}^1 dz\,dy\,dx=3/4$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks okay to me, although you might want to include a couple more steps of work before concluding that $V = \frac{3}{4}$